# ffmpeg batch command trim all mp3s in folder

Tags: php, batch-file, ffmpeg

I am working on a php shell_exec for ffmpeg,

I would like to select all the mp3 files in a folder and then trim them to 30 seconds and output them with the same name as the input but with a 2 after it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
shell_exec('ffmpeg -ss 5 -t 30 -i *.mp3 *+2.mp3');
```

Also do i just place the php file in the directory or do I have to specify the directory?

Comment: could you please write the complete command that you are trying . so that we get a clear picture what you are trying to do

Comment: Hey csharpcoder I would like to trim every mp3 in the folder using that command and have the ouput name be the same with a 2 after it ex input = test.mp3 output = test2.mp3

Comment: You should add `-c copy` to just re-mux otherwise you'll needlessly re-encode (unless you're re-encoding on purpose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this you must create a batch file command to run through the files.

In note pad I created the following command and saved it as batch.bat:

```
for %%a in ("*.*") do ffmpeg -ss 5 -t 30 -i "%%a" -acodec copy "newfiles\%%~na.mp3"
```

I had a copy of ffmpeg in the folder with the files and a new folder called newfiles

thanks to csharpcoder, LongNeckbeard, and the following link:
http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/356314-How-to-batch-convert-multiplex-any-files-with-ffmpeg

(I ended up just doing this in home windows pc v.s. on ubuntu server to save on some resources. Also the following command will copy the original name v.s. adding the two after which actually is better for what I wanted to do)

Answer (score 2):

For trimming first 30 seconds :

```
ffmpeg -ss 30 -i inputfile.mp3 -acodec copy outputfile.mp3
```

for keeping first 30 seconds and trimming the rest:

```
ffmpeg -t 30 -i inputfile.mp3 -acodec copy outputfile.mp3
```

Their is no direct way that you could apply in ffmpeg to trim each file inside a directory , 
so either you need to use some logic to iterate through each file in a folder and apply the ffmpeg command,

or else writing a batch file to do the same and invoking it from shell_exec would be a better option.

Hope this helps